# Asp.NET MVC3 + MySQL, always returns null

Tags: asp.net, mysql, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I am at a loss with this one. First of all, something strange:

every time I open a connection, (as shown in mysql logs), the following commands are excecuted:

```
SET character_set_results=NULL
SET NAMES utf8
SHOW COLLATION
SHOW VARIABLES
```

Then there is no select query at all!

A simple:

```
using (MyEntities myents = new MyEntities())
{
 var lala = (from r in myents.categories
                  select r).ToList();
        }
```

Will produce an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Even a .FirstOrDefault() produces the same error! (it should return null in case of empty dataset).

I think I broke asp.net!

Asp.net ver 4
MySQL connector 6.4.3
MVC 3 controller (same result is also inside a repository class etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the cause of mayhem, but why this bug occurs beats me:
(evil) NUGET added this:

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        [...]
            <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d"    culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.4.3.0" newVersion="6.4.3.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
     </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Deleting this from the config makes everything fine and dandy!

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified the `ConnectionString` correctly in the top level `Web.config` or `App.config` (i.e. the one that features the above code)?

Debug and try to find out if it's your `MyEntities` that is `null` or something else.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the reply. Yes connection string is correct: database schema updates fine through the auto update tool, and ELMAH logs (and displays) errors without a problem!

The entity object is populated with the appropriate objectsets, and up until the last IQueryable phase, everything seems to work out fine. Would a stack trace help?